# How to change usermin domain

Tags: webserver, webmin

Hello i have issue with changing usermin `https://localhost:20000` with some domain `example.com`.I wonder if anyone can explain me how to do it

Comment: Are you talking about `grunt`?  There's likely a better place to ask such a question, as this is for Ubuntu and distribution-specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to Usermin Configuration
- Go to Ports and Addresses
- Change Web Server Hostname